# Control of x86 registers through LLVM IR?

Tags: x86, llvm, llvm-ir

I want to apply an algorithm that assumes registers `R0, R1,...,Rn`.

In this case, what I want to control is which order these registers get assigned.

Is it possible at the LLVM IR level to control registers, or does the IR shields these low-level details away?

Comment: It is possible with inline assembly, which may not be what you want. The IR is more C level than assembly level on this aspect.

Comment: What method calls are available for inline assembly?

Comment: I don't understand the question?

Comment: You say it is possible with inline assembly, so I ask whether LLVM supports this?

Comment: Try using clang to get LLVM IR from some C + inline asm.

Answer (score 0):

You can use llvm.read_register and llvm.write_register on newer versions of llvm.

If you want a good example, try creating a global variable like so:

```
register void *rsp asm("rsp");
```

Then try printing it with printf. Compile the simple C program with -S -emit-llvm and you can see llvm.read_register is used

```
%4 = call i64 @llvm.read_register.i64(metadata !0)
```

And at the bottom of the file you will see metadata index 0 is:

```
!0 = !{!"rsp"}
```

Comment: But won't that turn into a `mov rax, rsp` or something?  It doesn't let you control what register `%4` is stored in.

Comment: That isn't always correct, but even if it wasn't the optimizer is sure to cause issues. Inline assembly is probably the best way to do what OP wants specifically